# What happened to Lazy<T> support in Autofac?

Tags: autofac

In beta builds of Autofac 2.1 there was support for automatic resolution of `Lazy<T>` as described in Nicholas Blumhardt's [Lazing Around with Autofac](http://nblumhardt.com/2009/12/lazing-around-with-autofac2/) blog post.

[The code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#15-NfL2P5pY/trunk/src/Source/Autofac.Integration.Mef/LazyDependencyModule.cs&q=Autofac.Integration.Mef%20package:http://autofac%5C.googlecode%5C.com&t=0&d=4) still seems to be in the source on Google Code, but I can't find `LazyDependencyModule` in any of the .NET 4.0 binaries I've looked at. Has it moved somewhere else?

How do I use Autofac's automatic `Lazy<T>` resolution with the latest Autofac builds?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to register `LazyDependencyModule` yourself in the production Autofac 2 builds. It is a part of the default container, so just register `T` and `Lazy<T>` will be provided.

Make sure you're not accidentally using a .NET 3.5 binary, too :)

Nick

Comment: You're right, I must have got my assembly versions in a pickle. It's working now, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem - it took me hours to find out.