# Pass parameter from a ViewModel to another with IoC

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm trying to instantiate a SecondViewModel from a MainViewModel injecting in this second one paramaters that are services registered in the IoCContainer and objects from the MainVM.

The code is something of this kind:

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
    }

    private string message = "the message";
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

class SecondViewModel
{
    public SecondViewModel(IService service, string message)
    {
    }
}
```

now, i know i can make the IoC Container inject a SecondViewModelFactory (that carries the service instance) into the MainViewModel, so it can create the SVM through it, but what if the implementation of IService is very heavy and i don't want to instantiate it but when i really need it.

And what if i have to instantiate other ViewModels in a similar way? Do I have to create tons of VMFactories and constructor's parameters?

And in case I use a generic ViewModelFactory, it would need to be instantiated passing all the services needed by every ViewModel I have, regardless if they will be created or not.

Do you know any better solution to my case?

Comment: Which IoC container you are using?

Comment: I'm using SimpleIoC of MVVM Light. But I can change it, I'm just a student who's trying to learn =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the creation of services should not be heavy. Their constructor should do nothing more than storing the incoming dependencies. If it uses some heavy resources in the background, they shouldn't be accessed through the constructor. This keeps the constructor simple (prevents you from having to test it) and allows the object graph to be composed very rapidly.

If there is really no way around this, there are basically two patterns you can apply:

**1. Factories**

You can inject a factory to delay the creation of a type. Factories are also useful when objects are created that should be controlled explicitly (for instance, instances that should be disposed as soon as possible). There are several ways of creating factories. Some people like to inject `Func<T>` or `Lazy<T>` dependencies into their services, but I find this too implicit. I rather inject an `ISomeServiceFactory`, since I find this more readable. Downside is that you need to define a new interface for this. However, if you find yourself having many factory interfaces, you probably have a [problem in your design](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100) anyway.

**2. Proxies**

Instead of creating a factory, you can hide the service behind a proxy. This proxy can implement the same interface as the service and will do the delayed execution for you. This prevents you from letting the application take a dependency on a different interface (an `IServiceFactory` or `Lazy<T>` for instance). Especially `Lazy<T>` leaks details about the creation into the consumer of such a dependency. You can still inject a `Lazy<T>` into this proxy, if that's convenient. That's not a problem. That proxy would typically be part of your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) and the rest of your application would still be dependend on your `IService` and not your `Lazy<IService>`.

Please be aware that the use of factories, proxies and lazy initiation does complicate the wiring of the container. So don't use if unless you measured that you really need it. They complicate things,  because of the indirection, which makes it harder to follow interlectually. And they make it harder to verify your configuration using automated tests. For more information about verifying your container, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371027/which-is-a-good-approach-to-test-ninject-bindings/12376609#12376609) and [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#verify-configuration).

Answer (score 1):

Most `IoC Containers` supports Lazy dependency to with `Lazy<>` to avoid creating expensive class immediately.

So in your code, you can make lazy for your expensive IService:

```
class SecondViewModel
{
    public SecondViewModel(Lazy<IService> service, string message)
    {
    }
}
```

You can use some popular IoC Containers and see how they support lazy loading: [Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075260/what-happened-to-lazyt-support-in-autofac) or [NInject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538132/lazy-loading-with-ninject)

Comment: And even when a container has no explicit support for `Lazy<T>`, you can simply register a `Lazy<T>`. This will even work with SimpleIoC.