# IoC - Delay initialization of services in controller until required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

In an ASP.NET MVC application, I'm calling "Services" methods from my controllers.

Usually, a controller named `ReportingController` calls methods from `ReportingServices`. The service classes are being instantiated with `Autofac` with the `Mvc.Integration`.

```
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

The service is then injected into the controller constructor.

```
public ReportingController(ReportingServices service)
```

So far so good.
But occasionally, a controller needs to call methods from other services. I changed the autofac configuration:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
       .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.PreserveSetValues);
```

And added properties to the controllers:

```
public CommonServices CommonService { get; set; } // new properties
public ReportingController(ReportingServices service) {} // existing ctor
```

What happens now however is that when the controller is instantiated, all properties are also being set, even if they are never used by a particular ActionMethod.

How can I tell Autofac to delay instantiation of the properties until required or perhaps I should simply not care about this unnecessary initialization?

Comment: Your controller may have too many responsibilities.

Comment: Use `Lazy<T>`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075260/what-happened-to-lazyt-support-in-autofac

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Do you mean that it is good practice to have pretty much a 1 on 1 relation between controllers and services? And that if a controller would suddenly need something from another service that this should perhaps be handled in the service itself and not in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autofac supports `Lazy<T>` [out of the box](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes).

So you just need to declare your property as:

```
public Lazy<CommonServices> CommonService { get; set; }
```

And Autofac won't instantiate your `CommonServices` until you don't access your Lazy's value with `CommonService.Value`.

Comment: until you don't access...?

Comment: @Alex Autofac won't create your `CommonServices` until you don't access it, so in the this example:  the `Value` property of the `CommonService` so if you don't write `CommonService.Value` then Autofac won't create your `CommonServices`